# Iterating through non-rectangular nested lists of objects column by column using for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-lists, iterable

I have a situation where I'm given a nested list that has very good odds of being non-rectangular.
For example:

```
lists = [[obj1,obj2,obj3],[obj4,obj5],[obj6,obj7,obj8,obj9]]
```

and I want to iterate over it such that x = obj1,obj4,obj6,obj2,obj5,obj7,obj3,obj8,0bj9.
Iterating over the elements of the first column, then the elements of the second column, and so on.

It could easily be done by transposing it and iterating over it, but I've yet to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Itertools is really handy for this. You can combine [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and `filter` to make an iterator that gives you the result you're looking for:

```
from itertools import zip_longest, chain

lists = [['obj1','obj2','obj3'],['obj4','obj5'],['obj6','obj7','obj8','obj9']]

it = filter(None, chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(*lists)))
list(it)
# ['obj1', 'obj4', 'obj6', 'obj2', 'obj5', 'obj7', 'obj3', 'obj8', 'obj9']
```

There is also a `roundrobin` function in the [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) that may be more efficient since it doesn't need to filter the `None` values, but it's not quite as succinct. You would call that with `roundrobin(*lists)` to get the desired result.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is exactly what I'm looking for! what's the purpose of the ```*``` in ```*lists```?

Comment: @Therk that spreads the individual sublists as argument. The same as `zip_longest(lists[0], lists[1], lists[2])`

Comment: From what I've seen today, it seems ```zip_longest()``` isn't necessary, I tried different things with it and I've settled on ```list(interleave_longest(*lists))``` which does exactly what I wanted. ```interleave_longest()``` is exactly the same as ```roundrobin()```, but is more efficient when given larger lists, which is the case for what I'm doing

Comment: Yes, `interleave_longest`  (and `roundrobin`) should work well. But, unlike itertools, it requires a library which isn't in the standard python distribution. Also, if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/more-itertools/more-itertools/blob/0b8e810c4ee23c87af5c265a7685fdec5d59ebb4/more_itertools/more.py) of `interleave_longest` you will see it just uses `zip_longest` under the hood.

Comment: luckily, we were already using ```more_itertools``` elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code using for loop nesting

```py
req_list =[]
for first in lists:
  for second in first:
      element = second
      req_list.append(element)
print(req_list)
```

Comment: Does not output in requested order, instead gives this: `['obj1', 'obj2', 'obj3', 'obj4', 'obj5', 'obj6', 'obj7', 'obj8', 'obj9']`